Stockfish Stop Command Not Working Consistently on Raspberry Pi when called too fast
I'm developing a software application designed to run on a Raspberry Pi 5 8gb as part of a smart chessboard project. The board will feature a touchscreen display. While my code is still a work in progress and somewhat poorly written (I apologize for that), it functions perfectly on my Mac, particularly in the Game Review section. This section is where multiple calculation commands are sent to Stockfish, depending on how quickly the user scrolls through the positions.
The main issue arises when I try to scroll quickly through the positions during Game Review. On my MacBook, the Stop Calculating function works flawlessly. No matter how quickly I click the forward and backward buttons to review the game, the software never crashes or freezes, and I consistently receive the log message "Stockfish has stopped calculating" as expected.
However, when I run the same software on a Raspberry Pi, the stop message frequently fails to appear, regardless of the maximum depth I set for calculations. I've tried various configurations, but nothing has worked so far.
My primary question is: at a high, production-ready level, how can I ensure that the stop command is sent reliably without errors, regardless of how quickly the commands are being issued?
Any insights or suggestions would be really really appreciated, I care a lot about this project and would like to complete it.
Thank you!
link to repo: https://github.com/Hardin22/JavaChessBoard.git
code for the stockfish class:
I implemented a method to send a stop command to Stockfish whenever the user rapidly scrolls through the game review positions. On my MacBook, the stop command works perfectly—Stockfish stops calculating instantly, even when rapidly clicking through moves. However, when I run the same software on a Raspberry Pi, the stop command frequently fails to execute, causing the engine to freeze or become unresponsive. I tried various configurations, including adjusting the maximum calculation depth/ movetime, and implementing different threading strategies, but none of these approaches resolved the issue on the Raspberry Pi. I was expecting the same consistent behavior as on my MacBook, where the stop command works reliably regardless of how fast the commands are issued.
package org.example.javachess.Oggetti;
import com.github.bhlangonijr.chesslib.Board;
import com.github.bhlangonijr.chesslib.Square;
import com.github.bhlangonijr.chesslib.move.Move;
import com.github.bhlangonijr.chesslib.move.MoveException;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import org.example.javachess.Utils.ChessMoveConverter;

public class Stockfish {

    private Process process1; // Per la valutazione della posizione
    private Process process3; // Per ottenere le prime tre mosse migliori
    private BufferedReader reader1;
    private BufferedReader reader3;
    private OutputStreamWriter writer1;
    private OutputStreamWriter writer3;
    private ChessMoveConverter ChessMoveConverter = new ChessMoveConverter();

    // Aggiungi questa variabile per il livello di abilità
    private int skillLevel;
    public Stockfish(String stockfishPath) {
        try {
            String line;

            ProcessBuilder pb3 = new ProcessBuilder(stockfishPath);
            process3 = pb3.start();
            reader3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process3.getInputStream()));
            writer3 = new OutputStreamWriter(process3.getOutputStream());

            writer3.write("uci\n");
            writer3.flush();

            while ((line = reader3.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Stockfish output: " + line); // Print each line for debugging
                if (line.equals("uciok")) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Set the number of threads
            writer3.write("setoption name Threads value 2\n");
            writer3.flush();
            System.out.println("Set Stockfish to use 2 threads.");

            // Set the hash size (e.g., 64 MB)
            writer3.write("setoption name Hash value 64\n");
            writer3.flush();
            System.out.println("Set Stockfish hash value to 64 MB.");

            // Confirm options are set
            writer3.write("isready\n");
            writer3.flush();

            while ((line = reader3.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Stockfish output: " + line); // Print confirmation output
                if (line.equals("readyok")) {
                    System.out.println("Stockfish is ready.");
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    // Funzione per impostare il livello di abilità
    public void setSkillLevel(int skillLevel) {
        this.skillLevel = skillLevel;
        try {
            writer1.write("setoption name Skill Level value " + skillLevel + "\n");
            writer1.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Funzione per ottenere la migliore mossa a seconda del livello di abilità

    public String getBestMove(String fen) {
        try {
            writer1.write("position fen " + fen + "\n");
            writer1.flush();

            writer1.write("go depth 10\n");
            writer1.flush();

            String line;
            while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.startsWith("bestmove")) {
                    return line.split(" ")[1];
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private volatile boolean isCalculating = false;
    // Funzione per valutare la posizione


    Color LIGHT_ORANGE = Color.rgb(242, 198, 126);
    Color LIGHT_GREEN = Color.rgb(175, 199, 119);





        // ... (altri metodi esistenti)

    public Map<Square, Double> evaluateMovesForPiece(Board board, Square pieceSquare, double currentEvaluation) {
        Map<Square, Double> moveEvaluations = new HashMap<>();
        ChessHelper chessHelper = new ChessHelper();

        try {
            // Ottieni tutte le mosse legali per il pezzo selezionato
            List<Square> legalMoves = chessHelper.getLegalMovesForPiece(board, pieceSquare);

            // Valuta ciascuna mossa
            for (Square toSquare : legalMoves) {
                Board tempBoard = new Board();
                tempBoard.loadFromFen(board.getFen());
                Move move = new Move(pieceSquare, toSquare);
                tempBoard.doMove(move);

                // Utilizza il writer1 per valutare rapidamente la posizione
                writer1.write("position fen " + tempBoard.getFen() + "\n");
                writer1.flush();

                writer1.write("go depth 7\n"); // Profondità bassa per velocità
                writer1.flush();

                String line;
                double evaluation = 0.0;
                boolean isMate = false;

                while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.startsWith("info depth 7")) {
                        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                        int scoreIndex = Arrays.asList(parts).indexOf("score");
                        if (scoreIndex != -1) {
                            String scoreType = parts[scoreIndex + 1];
                            if (scoreType.equals("cp")) {
                                evaluation = Integer.parseInt(parts[scoreIndex + 2]) / 100.0;
                            } else if (scoreType.equals("mate")) {
                                int mateIn = Integer.parseInt(parts[scoreIndex + 2]);
                                evaluation = mateIn > 0 ? 100.0 : -100.0;  // Usa 100 per rappresentare il matto
                                isMate = true; // Indica che si tratta di un matto
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (line.startsWith("bestmove")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Evaluation for " + toSquare + ": " + evaluation);

                // Calcola la differenza tra la valutazione attuale e quella della nuova posizione
                double evaluationDifference;
                if (isMate) {
                    // Per i matti, usa la differenza diretta
                    evaluationDifference =currentEvaluation-evaluation;
                } else {
                    // Negazione della valutazione per confrontarla correttamente
                    evaluationDifference = currentEvaluation - evaluation;
                }

                System.out.println("Evaluation difference: " + evaluationDifference);
                moveEvaluations.put(toSquare, isMate && evaluation == 0.0 ? 0.00 : evaluationDifference);                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return moveEvaluations;
        }
        //UTILIZZA I VALORI ASSOLUTIIIIIII PORCODIO


    // Nuova funzione per valutare le mosse legali di un pezzo

    public void highlightLegalMovesWithEvaluation(Board board, Square pieceSquare, ChessBoardUI chessBoard, double currentEvaluation) {
        Map<Square, Double> evaluations = evaluateMovesForPiece(board, pieceSquare, currentEvaluation);

        for (Map.Entry<Square, Double> entry : evaluations.entrySet()) {
            Square toSquare = entry.getKey();
            double evalDifference = entry.getValue();

            Color color;
            if (evalDifference > -0.5) {
                color = Color.GREEN; // Buona mossa
            } else if (evalDifference < 0.5 && evalDifference > -1.0) {
                color = Color.YELLOW; // Mossa neutra o imprecisione
            } else if (evalDifference < -1.0 && evalDifference > -2.0) {
                color = Color.ORANGE; // Errore o mossa sbagliata
            } else {
                color = Color.RED; // Blunder o mossa cattiva
            }

            int col = toSquare.ordinal() % 8;
            int row = 7 - (toSquare.ordinal() / 8);
            chessBoard.highlightSquare(col, row, color);
        }
    }








    // Funzione per convertire la mossa UCI in coordinate e disegnare la freccia
    private void drawArrowFromMove(String moveInUci, ChessBoardUI chessBoard, Color color) {
        // Converti la mossa in coordinate
        int fromCol = moveInUci.charAt(0) - 'a';
        int fromRow = '8' - moveInUci.charAt(1);
        int toCol = moveInUci.charAt(2) - 'a';
        int toRow = '8' - moveInUci.charAt(3);

        // Disegna la freccia sulla scacchiera
        chessBoard.drawArrowOnBoard(fromCol, fromRow, toCol, toRow, color);
    }



    // Funzione per ottenere le prime tre mosse migliori



    // Funzione per chiudere Stockfish
    public void close() {
        try {
            if (process1 != null) {
                writer1.write("quit\n");
                writer1.flush();
                writer1.close();
                reader1.close();
                process1.destroy();
            }

            if (process3 != null) {
                writer3.write("quit\n");
                writer3.flush();
                writer3.close();
                reader3.close();
                process3.destroy();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //test per le linee principali//


    public void getTopThreeMoves(String fen, Label move1Label, Label move2Label, Label move3Label, ChessBoardUI chessBoard, Label evaluationLabel, EvalBar evalBar) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            if (isCalculating) {
                stopCalculating(writer3, reader3, process3);
                isCalculating = false;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            isCalculating = true;
            try {
                writer3.write("setoption name MultiPV value 3\n");
                writer3.flush();

                writer3.write("position fen " + fen + "\n");
                writer3.flush();

                writer3.write("go movetime 3000\n");
                writer3.flush();

                String line;
                String[] topMoves = new String[3];
                String[] moveEvaluations = new String[3]; // Array per memorizzare le valutazioni
                String[] fullLines = new String[3]; // Array per memorizzare le linee di mosse complete

                while ((line = reader3.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.startsWith("info depth ")) {
                        processStockfishOutput(line, fen, topMoves, moveEvaluations, fullLines, chessBoard, move1Label, move2Label, move3Label, evaluationLabel, evalBar);
                    } else if (line.startsWith("bestmove")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                isCalculating = false;
                System.out.println("calcoli finiti");
            }
        }).start();
    }


    private void stopCalculating(OutputStreamWriter writer, BufferedReader reader, Process process) {
        try {
            if (process != null) {
                System.out.println("Sending stop command to Stockfish...");
                writer.write("stop\n");
                writer.flush();

                // Wait for confirmation from Stockfish
                String line;
                boolean stopped = false;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Received from Stockfish: " + line);
                    if (line.startsWith("info") && line.contains("nodes") || line.startsWith("bestmove")) {
                        stopped = true;
                        System.out.println("Stockfish has stopped calculating.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!stopped) {
                    System.out.println("Did not receive stop confirmation, waiting a bit longer...");
                    Thread.sleep(100);  // Aspetta un po' e riprova
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("isCalculating set to false.");
    }


    private void processStockfishOutput(String line, String fen, String[] topMoves, String[] moveEvaluations, String[] fullLines,
                                        ChessBoardUI chessBoard, Label move1Label, Label move2Label, Label move3Label, Label evaluationLabel, EvalBar evalBar) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        int multiPVIndex = Arrays.asList(parts).indexOf("multipv");
        if (multiPVIndex != -1) {
            int pv = Integer.parseInt(parts[multiPVIndex + 1]) - 1;
            if (pv < 3) {
                int pvIndex = Arrays.asList(parts).indexOf("pv");
                if (pvIndex == -1 || pvIndex + 1 >= parts.length) {
                    return; // Linea PV malformata
                }
                int moveIndex = pvIndex + 1;
                int scoreIndex = Arrays.asList(parts).indexOf("score");

                if (scoreIndex == -1 || scoreIndex + 2 >= parts.length) {
                    return; // Linea score malformata
                }

                double adjustedScore = calculateAdjustedScore(parts, scoreIndex, fen);
                String moveEvaluation = formatMoveEvaluation(parts, scoreIndex, adjustedScore);
                fullLines[pv] = buildFullLine(moveIndex, parts, fen, moveEvaluation);

                topMoves[pv] = parts[moveIndex];
                moveEvaluations[pv] = moveEvaluation;

                updateUI(pv, topMoves[pv], fullLines[pv], adjustedScore, chessBoard, move1Label, move2Label, move3Label, evaluationLabel, evalBar, moveEvaluations);
            }
        }
    }

    private double calculateAdjustedScore(String[] parts, int scoreIndex, String fen) {
        String scoreType = parts[scoreIndex + 1];
        String[] fenParts = fen.split(" ");
        String sideToMove = fenParts.length > 1 ? fenParts[1] : "w"; // Default a "w" se il parsing fallisce

        if (scoreType.equals("cp")) {
            double score = Double.parseDouble(parts[scoreIndex + 2].replace(",", ".")) / 100.0;
            return sideToMove.equals("b") ? -score : score;
        } else if (scoreType.equals("mate")) {
            int mateIn = Integer.parseInt(parts[scoreIndex + 2]);

            if (mateIn > 0) {
                if (sideToMove.equals("w")) {
                    // Bianco può fare scacco matto in mateIn mosse
                    return mateIn;
                } else {
                    // Nero può fare scacco matto in mateIn mosse, quindi è negativo per bianco
                    return -mateIn;
                }
            } else { // mateIn < 0
                if (sideToMove.equals("w")) {
                    // Bianco sarà messo sotto scacco matto in abs(mateIn) mosse, quindi negativo
                    return mateIn;
                } else {
                    // Nero sarà messo sotto scacco matto in abs(mateIn) mosse, quindi positivo per bianco
                    return -mateIn;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0.0; // Valore di default in caso di errore
    }

    private String formatMoveEvaluation(String[] parts, int scoreIndex, double adjustedScore) {
        String scoreType = parts[scoreIndex + 1];
        if (scoreType.equals("cp")) {
            return String.format("%.2f", adjustedScore);
        } else if (scoreType.equals("mate")) {
            int mateIn = (int) Math.abs(adjustedScore);
            if (adjustedScore > 0) {
                return "#" + mateIn;
            } else {
                return "#-" + mateIn;
            }
        }
        return "N/A";
    }

    private String buildFullLine(int moveIndex, String[] parts, String fen, String moveEvaluation) {
        StringBuilder fullLine = new StringBuilder();
        fullLine.append("[").append(moveEvaluation).append("] ");
        int moveNumber = 1;
        boolean isWhiteMove = true;

        Board board = new Board();
        board.loadFromFen(fen);  // Carica il FEN iniziale

        for (int i = moveIndex; i < parts.length; i++) {
            if (isWhiteMove) {
                fullLine.append(moveNumber).append(")");
                moveNumber++;
            }

            String uciMove = parts[i];
            String algebraicMove = ChessMoveConverter.convertToAlgebraicNotation(uciMove, board.getFen());
            fullLine.append(algebraicMove).append(" ");

            // Esegui la mossa sulla scacchiera per aggiornare il FEN
            try {
                Move move = new Move(Square.valueOf(uciMove.substring(0, 2).toUpperCase()),
                        Square.valueOf(uciMove.substring(2, 4).toUpperCase()));
                board.doMove(move);
            } catch (MoveException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            isWhiteMove = !isWhiteMove;
        }
        return fullLine.toString().trim();
    }


    private void updateUI(int pv, String move, String fullLine, double adjustedScore, ChessBoardUI chessBoard, Label move1Label, Label move2Label, Label move3Label, Label evaluationLabel, EvalBar evalBar, String[] moveEvaluations) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (pv == 0) {
                chessBoard.clearArrows();
            }

            switch (pv) {
                case 0 -> {
                    move1Label.setText(fullLine);
                    drawArrowFromMove(move, chessBoard, LIGHT_GREEN);
                }
                case 1 -> {
                    move2Label.setText(fullLine);
                    drawArrowFromMove(move, chessBoard, LIGHT_ORANGE);
                }
                case 2 -> {
                    move3Label.setText(fullLine);
                    drawArrowFromMove(move, chessBoard, LIGHT_ORANGE);
                }
            }

            if (pv == 0) {
                evaluationLabel.setText("Evaluation: " + moveEvaluations[0]);
                if (moveEvaluations[0].startsWith("#")) {
                    // Se si tratta di uno scacco matto, passiamo un valore estremo per indicarlo
                    int mateIn = Integer.parseInt(moveEvaluations[0].replace("#", "").replace("-", ""));
                    double evalScore = moveEvaluations[0].contains("-") ? -1000.0 + mateIn : 1000.0 - mateIn;
                    evalBar.updateEvaluation(evalScore);
                } else {
                    evalBar.updateEvaluation(adjustedScore);
                }
            }
        });
    }


}



Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
